# How to pass data from a component into getServerSideProps

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js, server-side-rendering

I'm having trouble figuring out how to pass data from a component to getServerSideProps, basically what I want is to get the value of text input and use it as a keyword in my API call.
The text input will be located in a "SearchBar" component that will be visible on every page of my application and on button click I want to make the API call using the value of the input in a proper page called "SearchResults".
What is the best way to do that?

SearchBar:

```
import { useState } from 'react';

export default function SearchBar() {
  const [keyword, setKeyword] = useState('');

  const handleClick = (event) => {
    event.preventDefault();
    console.log(keyword);
  };
  return (
    <div>
      <input
        type="text"
        value={keyword}
        onChange={(e) => setKeyword(e.target.value)}
      />
      <button onClick={handleClick}>Fetch</button>
    </div>
  );
}
```

SearchResults:

```
import { GetServerSideProps } from 'next';

export const getServerSideProps: GetServerSideProps = async (context) => {
  const { keyword } = context;
  const res = await fetch(
    `https://www.googleapis.com/books/v1/volumes?q=${keyword}`
  );
  const data = await res.json();

  return { props: {} };
};

export default function SearchResults() {
  return (
    <div>
      <h1>Teste</h1>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

i am guessing, that your api call for the textinput will be a client side call, because it needs client interaction on top of it.

> So no need to do server side calls.

Just onChange call your api, and it will be done.

```
import { useState } from 'react';

export default function SearchBar() {
  const [keyword, setKeyword] = useState('');

  const handleClick = (event) => {
    event.preventDefault();
    fetchData(keyword);
  };

  const fetchData = async(keyword) => {
     const res = await fetch(
    `https://www.googleapis.com/books/v1/volumes?q=${keyword}`
  );

  const data = await res.json();
  };


  return (
    <div>
      <input
        type="text"
        value={keyword}
        onChange={(e) => setKeyword(e.target.value)}
      />
      <button onClick={handleClick}>Fetch</button>
    </div>
  );
}
```

lastly, you can wrap your component with layout, so that your search component will be visible in every page.

```
// pages/_app.js

import SearchComponent from '../components/SearchComponent'

export default function MyApp({ Component, pageProps }) {
  return (
    <div>
      <SearchComponent/>
      <Component {...pageProps} />
    </div>
  )
}
```

Refer here for [nextjs layouts](https://nextjs.org/docs/basic-features/layouts)

Answer (score 1):

you wrap the input with form:

```
<form onSubmit={submitHandler} >
     <input
        type="text"
        value={keyword}
        onChange={(e) => setKeyword(e.target.value)}
      />
</form>
```

write submitHandler:

```
const submitHandler = (event) => {
    event.preventDefault();
    if (keyword) {
      Router.push({
        // whatever your baseUrl
        pathname: process.env.BASE_URL,
        query: { keyword: keyword, page: 1 },
      });
    // Optional
    } else if (keyword === "") {
      Router.push({ pathname: "", query: { page: 1 } });
    } else {
      Router.push(Router.router.asPath);
    }
  };
```

then in getServerSideProps you reach the query the way you wrote the code